# Make revisions on other's posts distinguishable from my own in profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, information-display, activity-summary

When viewing the activity tab of a profile, all entries generally have the same exact format and style:

> timestamp type [expansion-button] question-title

At least amongst the categories, the type usually has a different color.  This is good and all.  Couldn't we make it better?  Everywhere else, owner and non-owner, questions and answers have distinct styles.  However in the profile page, we have something that looks like:

[image: current revisions view]

Could the styles in which they are displayed be similar to how they are elsewhere on the site?

[image: examples]

Question/Answer owners usually have a colored background on their name (as seen in a post revision page).  Questions in search show a bigger vote count box and more noticeable compared to answers (a view where they shown intermixed and distinguishable).  Maybe something like:

[image: mockup]

Perhaps changes could be made for the other types as well.  Hopefully it wouldn't clash with others' styles too much.

Comment: I think this would be a useful feature; I came to post the same thing and eventually found this one.